# Add a download button to playing facebook video in android webview

Tags: java, android, webview

Please how do i add a download button to a playing facebook video in android's webview as shown in the image below.Thanks (https://i.stack.imgur.com/pk8MH.jpg)

I tried doing this -
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // Enable JavaScript

```
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true); // Enable DOM storage (might be required for some websites)
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(false); // Disable file access
    webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(false); // Disable content access
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(false); // Disable file access from file URLs
    webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(false); // Disable universal access from file URLs


    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "Android"); // Add JavaScript interface
    webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2; en-gb; VidSnap Build/FRF50) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1");
    headers.put("HTTP_X-Requested-With","com.android.chrome");
    webView.loadUrl(getIntent().getStringExtra("URL"), headers);


    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.startsWith("fb://")) {
                // Handle Facebook URL scheme internally or perform a specific action
                // For example, you can open the Facebook app or show an error message
                return true; // Prevent the WebView from loading the URL
            } else {
                // Load other URLs in the WebView
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            // Handle error situations
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedHttpError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse) {
            // Handle HTTP error situations
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // Perform video detection here
            webView.evaluateJavascript("javascript:(function() {" +
                    "var videoElement = document.querySelector('video');" +
                    "if (videoElement) {" +
                    "   var thumbnailUrl = videoElement.poster;" +
                    "   if (thumbnailUrl) {" +
                    "       Android.onThumbnailDetected(thumbnailUrl);" +
                    "   }" +
                    "}})();", null);
        }
    });
```